# How can I create and kill a list of threads in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I don't know how to put the ThreadIds running in a list and, then, killing all the thread created.

I've tried some Monads operations but I could't understand the type erros in ghci.

```hs
import Control.Concurrent

main = do 
  ts <- [forkIO(write 'a'), forkIO(write 'b')];
  putStrLn "Stop printing as and bs!";
  map killThread ts;
  where
    write c = do 
      putChar c;
      write c;
```

I expected the code to run two other threads in parallel and then killing this two threads.

Comment: Please include the type error messages in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `Control.Monad.mapM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]`

Example:

```
main = do 
  ts <- mapM forkIO [(write 'a'), (write 'b')]
  putStrLn "Stop printing as and bs!"
  _ <- mapM killThread ts -- or use mapM_ for no returning result effect
  pure () -- return ()
  where
    write c = do 
      putChar c
      write c
```

And you don't have to use semicolon in haskell `;`. Just correction indentation is enough.

Comment: Your solution made it just fine. The only mistake is that, in main function, the last line must be an expression. 

```The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
```